# Hosting Cacti install from NginX

Tags: nginx, configuration, cacti

I have having an issue with hosting a Cacti installation from NginX.

I have cacti installed under /usr/share/cacti and the below block in my default NginX config file.

```
location / {
    root /var/www;
    index index.html index.htm
}

location /cacti {
    root /usr/share/cacti;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$request_filename;
    }
}
```

The problem as I can see is that the NginX error log is full of errors that "/usr/share/cacti/cacti/index.php" doesn't exist.

For now I have simply added the extra directory to cacti, but I can't figure how to get NginX to 'drop' the '/cacti/' prefix from the URI when processing the page requests (and passing them on to PHP5-FPM)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try just changing location line from "location /cacti {" to "location / {"

Comment: The "location /" already has a root of /var/www - Updated post to add this

Comment: might be worth noting that you are missing a semi-colon after `index.html index.htm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `root` directive still results in the URL path being appended, so if the root is `/usr/share/cacti` and the path is `/cacti` the directory is `/usr/share/cacti/cacti`. You can do one of two things:

1. Since your URL path matches the directory, set the root one level higher:

   ```
   location /cacti {
       root /usr/share;
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Use the [`alias`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#alias) directive, which doesn't append the URL path. This approach will require modifying the `SCRIPT_FILENAME` parameter passed to PHP however.

   ```
   location /cacti {
       alias /usr/share/cacti;
       ...
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share$request_filename;
   }
   ```

Comment: When I use the alias directive, the pages fail to load and my NginX log shows that PHP-FPM is still looking for the scripts in /usr/share/cacti/cacti/...

Comment: @TimJones See my edit. I'd go with the first option.